# SQL state 37000 in SQLConnect when connecting to MS SQL database

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a PHP script which uses as read-only account in order to connect to a MS SQL database.
I was working prefectly until recently, when the DB admin changed something with my account.
Now I only get the following error message:

> E_WARNING Error in file "dbconnect.php" at line 40: odbc_connect():
>   SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open
>   database "dbname" requested by the login. The login failed., SQL state
>   37000 in SQLConnect

My connection code looks like this:

```
    <?php
    $user = 'username';
    $pass = 'password';
    $server = 'servername';
    $database1 = 'dbname';  
    $CharacterSet = "UTF-8";

    $connection_string1 = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$server;DATABASE=$database1;CharacterSet=$CharacterSet"; 
    $conn = odbc_connect($connection_string1,$user,$pass);
    ?>
```

I was also unable to connect to the database via the same account via SQL Management Studio, but then I found the following blog post which suggested to change the default database to 'master' on connection:

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/11/04/sql-server-fix-error-4064-cannot-open-user-default-database-login-failed-login-failed-for-user/

Is it possible to do the same via odbc_connect somehow?

Comment: "DB admin changed something with my account" what did they change with your account?

Comment: I'd suggest talking to the Database Administrator. If they have "changed something" which has caused the connection to fail then only they will know what they have changed, and they'll know what to do to fix it. I would hazard a guess they have changed the permissions of your login or user.

Comment: connecting to master wont help you if you need access to this database. You might establish a connection to sql server but will get the error again once you try any command on that database. Talk to your DB admin and let him fix it, he probably does not know he broke something

Comment: Or maybe you need to use another login to this database now and nobody told you yet. Again your DB Admin will know this